# Resume backup of a azure VM, Powershell command

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I just disabled the backup of my Azure VM and moved it to another subscriptions with all dependencies. Now I want to resume the backup using Powershell command. But I find that there is only some command for enable or disable backup, is there anything to resume a backup ?

Comment: If you mean to restore a VM, you can see the PowerShell command [`Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.recoveryservices/restore-azrecoveryservicesbackupitem?view=azps-1.6.0).

Comment: Sorry, I want to resume the backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know there is **enable** or **disable** operation for Azure VM backup. I think there is no such ***resume*** backup operation. Per my understanding, I suppose what you want is to continue backups the Azure VM in the existing recovery service vault after you move the Azure VM to another subscription. If so, please note that

> Recovery Services vault doesn't support cross subscription backups. If
>   you move a vault with virtual machine backup data across
>   subscriptions, you must move your virtual machines to the same
>   subscription, and use the same target resource group to continue
>   backups.

To move a virtual machine to a new subscription without moving the Recovery Services vault:

> 1. Temporarily stop backup
> 2. Delete the restore point. This operation deletes only the instant recovery points, not the backed-up data in the vault.
> 3. Move the virtual machines to the new subscription
> 4. Reprotect it under a new vault in that subscription

In this case, you have to create a new vault for Azure VM backup after you move the VM to another subscription, so you will use `Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection` to enable backup for an Azure VM then start a backup job with `Backup-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem`.

Otherwise, you can [move a Recovery Services vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-move-recovery-services-vault#use-azure-portal-to-move-a-recovery-services-vault-to-a-different-subscription) and its associated resources to another subscription. Currently, you can move one Recovery Services vault, per region, at a time. You can't move vaults that back up Azure Files, Azure File Sync, or SQL in IaaS virtual machines. To move a Recovery Services vault, you must [enroll in a limited public preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-move-recovery-services-vault).

You also could get more details from the [recovery service limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#recovery-services-limitations).

Comment: here I would like to resume backup through powershell script after disabling my VM backup using powershell script. If I run enable backup protection its failing with item is not protected. So please suggest me how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resume ? Just Re-enable vm backup?

Reference: [Enable backup for an Azure VM](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/backup/quick-backup-vm-powershell.md) and [Back up a virtual machine in Azure with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/backup/quick-backup-vm-powershell?view=azps-1.4.0)

> You enable backup for an Azure VM, and specify a backup policy.
>
> The policy defines when backups run, and how long recovery points created by the backups should be retained.
>       The default protection policy runs a backup once a day for the VM, and retains the created recovery points for 30 days. You can use this default policy to quickly protect your VM.
>
> Enable backup as follows:
>
> First, set the default policy with Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy:

```
    $policy = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy     -Name "DefaultPolicy"
```

> Enable VM backup with Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection. Specify the policy, the resource group and the VM name.

```bsh
    Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection `
        -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
        -Name "myVM" `
        -Policy $policy
```